# CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`%` EVENT IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, scheduler, privileges

everytime I try to schedule a new event on mysql 5.5.23,

I get the following error:

```
"Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database".
```

I've already checked the privileges of root account:

```
"GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, 
       REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, 
       LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, 
       SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
       IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION".
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: You seem not to have been granted the privilege [EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_event).

Comment: thank You!
if I run "GRANT EVENT ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost`;" the response is "Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)"

Answer (score 0):

As @wchiquito pointed out in the comments to the question:

> You seem not to have been granted the privilege EVENT

This can be easily fixed with:

```
GRANT EVENT ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
   IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
   WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**NOTE:** in your question you refer to user `'root'@'%'`. However, in the comments to the question you talk about `'root'@'localhost'`. In MySQL those are different entities.